# Why heapsort time complexity is given in Big-Oh(N log N) in CLRS algorithm book and not in Theta?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, notation, heapsort

Why in CLRS book time complexity of heapsort is specifically given as   Ο(N log N) while all other algorithms are in Θ notation? 
I am feeling like I am missing something from the intuition.

Here is image of the compexities given in book.

[image]

Comment: Judging from description in previous page of the table: `We omit the average-case running time of heapsort because we do not analyze it in
this book.`, I assume the same applies for the worst case complexity. The analysis of Heapsort in the book was done in big-O, not Theta, thus they added only big-O. (this is speculative)

Comment: So it would be right to say that its time complexity can be proven to be Theta(N log N) ? Everywhere on the internet it shows Big-Oh.

Comment: Given the fact that sorting problem, as general, is Omega(nlogn), yes, it is both Omega(nlogn) and O(nlogn), thus Theta(nlogn)